# Control video player with button and change scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a FMV game and I would like to figure out a way to control the video player with a UI button to change scene but only after the clip has finished playing.

If the user doesn't pick anything it will automatically be a default pathway and I have managed to use loopPoinReached and it has worked.

I can figure out how to use the same loopPointReached with a button.

Here is the video player code and it will auto load the next scene.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class loadBaseCampSeq : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");

        var videoPlayer = camera.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();


        videoPlayer.renderMode = UnityEngine.Video.VideoRenderMode.CameraNearPlane;


        videoPlayer.url = "Assets/VideoAssets/intro.mp4";

        videoPlayer.isLooping = false;


        videoPlayer.Play();

        videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached;

    }

    void EndReached(UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer vp)
    {
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("baseCampSeq");
    }
}
```

Here is the basic code that I have assigned to the UI Button On Click ()

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class loadTruckButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void truckSeq()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("truckSeq");
    }
}
```

I have been trying to reference the "EndReached" from the other script in the button but I cannot figure it out.

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to segregate the videoplayer functionality from the loadBaseCampSeq class into a new class. In the loadBaseCampSeq class create a videoplayer (instance) field and an abstract EndReached method:

```
public abstract class loadBaseCampSeq
{
   public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

   public abstract void EndReached();
}
```

Create a button class which inherits from the loadBaseCampSeq base class. In the button class override the EndReached method that uses the videoplayer instance from it's base class:

```
public class Button : loadBaseCampSeq
{
   public override class EndReached()
   {
      videoPlayer.EndReached();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting the following errors with the button class:Error CS1519 Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error CS1513 } expected  
Error CS1514 { expected 
Error CS1022 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected 
Error CS8124 Tuple must contain at least two elements. 
Error CS8124 Tuple must contain at least two elements. 
Error CS1519 Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error CS1519 Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Any idea why?

Comment: @Mehdi these errors are syntax errors, so you'll have to check these one-by-one. I can't solve them for you because these are out of scope from the initial question asked and without insight inside your entire codebase can't be solved. My advice would be to open those scripts in visual studio, because there you can use the intellisense to check where those errors occur.